# Retrieving child values from Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I have a query the looks for a specific UUID and returns the object.

```
print(snapshot)  
Snap (users) {
"-KENROf9kGUPw1j6ghFo" =     {
    UUID = "A1166D66-31B4-4B1C-B28C-58E9E5615D16";
    nickname = Craig;
};
}
```

I'm trying to extract the `nickname` but having trouble.

Here is my query `let queryRef = Firebase(url:"https://<url>.firebaseio.com/users")`

And here is the query reference.

```
var handle = queryRef.queryOrderedByChild("UUID").queryEqualToValue("A1166D66-31B4-4B1C-B28C-58E9E5615D16").observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
        if snapshot.value is NSNull {
            print("snapshot empty")
        } else {
            print(snapshot) //this prints the snapshot above
            self.nickname = snapshot.value.objectForKey("nickname") as! String  //this returns an error
            print(self.nickname)
        }
    })
}
```

The `self.nickname....` line returns the following error.

`fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`  I've tried a few different ways of structuring this, but have not yet found a way that doesn't fail.

Answer (score 1):

You're storing the users under a push id and then querying them by their uid. That's a bad idea. Instead, store the users under their uid (or in your case UUID) as this sample from the [Firebase documentation on storing user data](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/user-auth.html#section-storing) shows:

```
ref.authUser("jenny@example.com", password:"correcthorsebatterystaple") {
    error, authData in
    if error != nil {
        // Something went wrong. :(
    } else {
        // Authentication just completed successfully :)
        // The logged in user's unique identifier
        println(authData.uid)
        // Create a new user dictionary accessing the user's info
        // provided by the authData parameter
        let newUser = [
            "provider": authData.provider,
            "displayName": authData.providerData["displayName"] as? NSString as? String
        ]
        // Create a child path with a key set to the uid underneath the "users" node
        // This creates a URL path like the following:
        //  - https://<YOUR-FIREBASE-APP>.firebaseio.com/users/<uid>
        ref.childByAppendingPath("users")
           .childByAppendingPath(authData.uid).setValue(newUser)
    }
}
```

If you insist sticking to your current data structure, you'll need to handle the fact that a `.Value` query returns a list of children. Even if there's only one item that matches the query condition, it will still be a list of one item.

```
var query = queryRef.queryOrderedByChild("UUID").queryEqualToValue("A1166D66-31B4-4B1C-B28C-58E9E5615D16")
query.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
    if snapshot.value is NSNull {
       print("snapshot empty")
    } else {
        for child in snapshot.children {
            self.nickname = child.value.objectForKey("nickname") as! String
            print(self.nickname)
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: So I followed your advice and switched to storing the user by the iPhone UUID.  The app doesn't require passwords or authentication.  When the user logs in it just checks if their UUID has been logged prior.  Anyway, I can no longer get the query to work `let query = Firebase(url:"firebaseurl.com/users/")` and the query is `var handle = query.queryOrderedByChild("users").queryEqualToValue(UUID).observeEventType(.Value, withBlock ......`  Even when I feed it a known UUID, it still print's `snapshot empty`.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line:

```
self.nickname = snapshot.value.objectForKey("nickname") as! String
```

with the following:

```
self.nickname = snapshot.value["nickname"] as! String
```

And make sure that your snapshot is an object with a property "nickname"